# Is sequential workflow console application available in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have Visual Studio 2010 beta2 installed in my system.
The Issue is I am not finding Sequential Workflow console application option under
File ->New -> Project->Workflow for (.net framework 4).

I am trying to learn a workflow example tutorial for workflow 4.0.

But in that example -explaining to create a new Sequentialworkflow Console application.

Does Sequential Workflow console application available in VS2010?if yes why is it not found here ?

Can anyone please advise?.

Thanks

SNA

Comment: Could you post a link to the example?

Answer (score 3):

They have doen alot of rework in Workflow 4.0 compared to 3.5 and 3.0. There is no state machine workflow yet that you can use. With respect to a sequential workflow, you can add a Sequence activity into your console workflow appication and all should be good. Isn't that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

That exact option does not exist in the RC version either. You might be able to perform the tutorial using the `Workflow\Workflow Console Application` template.

**EDIT:**
It would appear that they have Sequential work flows are only for WF 3.5. For .NET 4 it looks like you can use an 'Activity' to create sequential or state machine workflows.

I tried creating an application using `File` -> `New Project` -> `Workflow` -> `Workflow Console Application`. Then I added an Activity, under `Workflow` -> `Activity`, which looks like it has everything that the previous sequential template had.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But the example ask for sequence workflow and Console.Read etc which i cant find out Workflow\Workflow Console Application toolBox

Comment: How do i create Time machine work flow..? where is Console.Readline ,eventcEventDriven.AddExternalevent ,clientOperation activity? I need to create a sequential activity which consume a web service using the clientOperation activity.But client operation activity also not available in toolbox.same for Console.readline.

Comment: I am not very familiar with how to use WF or the specific activies. As @Derar mentioned there have been alot of changes between WF 3.5 and 4. See this post (http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/pascal/archive/2009/05/20/wf-4-0-what-is-different-from-3-x.aspx) for more information on the differences.

I was able to find this example, (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WF4Services.aspx), for WF 4 where they have written a console application that then calls a web service to retrieve data and another that hosts a WF service. This might help.

Comment: i was able to create this using SendAndRecieveReply control in a sequential Activity.